# No carga Listbox VBA

Tags: vba

Quisiera pedir ayuda con una macro en la que estoy trabajando.
Estoy con un combobox en donde estan los clientes. Al seleccionar alguno y presionar buscar, intento traer todoas las coincidencias desde una planilla maestra a un Listbox.

La llamada la hago desde un comboBox para buscar por cliente, pero solo me está trayendo el ultimo dato ingresado.
En el ejemplo del Cliente A, al filtrar son 8 registros y solo me muestra la primera fila encontrada.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código de mi Botón buscar (con el cliente seleccionado en el combo box)

```
Private Sub google2_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim buscar2
buscar2 = texto2.Value

    If buscar2 <> Empty Then
    Sheets("Hoja1").Unprotect Password:="cr123"
            Hoja1.ListObjects("Tabla1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=36, Criteria1:= _
                buscar2

                UserForm2.lista.List = Range("Tabla1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value2

             Sheets("Hoja1").Protect Password:="cr123"

        Else: MsgBox "Debe introducir un valor"
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Les agradezco desde ya